# How does a post get edited by the "Community" moderator bot?

Tags: discussion, community

I noticed that this question was edited by the Community moderator bot. I actually wasn't aware that this existed, but when I read the profile page and saw that it's not a real person and supposedly just does automated things I couldn't help but wonder how this happened. I noticed that one of its tasks is to "own suggested edits from anonymous users." Is that most likely what happened here? And how does that process work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted one purpose of the Community moderator bot is to "own suggested edits from anonymous users." If an anonymous user suggests an edit, it is flagged for moderator attention, and if the moderator approves it, the edit is attributed to the "Community".

Moderators have wide latitude to approve or reject edits and make their best judgement based on personal experience with the subject matter as well as the nature and culture of the Stack Exchange site.

Comment: That makes sense. But I'm surprised to find out that anonymous users can edit posts. Wouldn't that open up the possibility for a troll to come in and wreak havoc on the site?

Comment: Ok, I had interpreted "anonymous" as "unregistered." But I just logged out and logged in and it seems that a user can't edit posts. So how does a user edit a post anonymously?

Comment: @jimirings If you're not logged in you should see "improve this question" under questions (and "improve this answer" under answers). The edit isn't displayed until it's approved.

Comment: I believe the edits can be approved by users with over 2000 rep (same level that you get direct edit instead of suggesting edits), but requires multiple users to approve. One moderator is enough to approve a suggested edit, though.